# Linked file in Eclipse not found by C files when building project

Tags: eclipse, build, eclipse-cdt

I created a linked file in eclipse, it was created fine and I can see it in the folder where I created it.

However, when I go an build the project I get an error saying:

```
fatal error: myfile.h: No such file or directory
```

If I instead place the actual file in that folder it builds fine.

Do I need to do something additional?

Pd. I already refreshed the project and did a clean build...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eclipse links are just in the Eclipse workspace, they don't change the actual file system - so an external compiler such as the C compiler won't see them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  so is there any workaround? - I wonder what is the usefulness of these linked files then

Comment: Linked files work well with Java which is much more tightly integrated with Eclipse. If you are using Linux or macOS you can use the `ln` command to create file system links.

Comment: Thanks Greg - unfortunately, I am using Windows (not my choice though)...